# Check if current time is between 6pm and 6am local time

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I have a job that needs to run in our pod between 6pm to 6am Arizona time, which is 1pm UTC to 1AM UTC which is our pods date.

I want to verify this code is accurate

```
if (now_time := datetime.now().time()) >= time(1, 00) and now_time <= time(13, 00):
    do stuff
```

The way this reads is get time right now (in UTC) and if it is greater than 1am UTC or 6pm AZ and if right now is less than 13am UTC or 6am AZ to run. Is the logic correct? Is there is a better way to do this time comparison?

Comment: What is the start time? 1pm or 1am? Your question title does not agree with the comparison in the code (the code checks if it is _after_ 1am and before 1pm).

Comment: Simplified: `time(1) <= datetime.now().time() <= time(13)`

Comment: *"6pm to 6am Arizona time, which is 1pm UTC to 1AM UTC"* -- that's incorrect. 6pm-6am MST is 1am-1pm UTC.

Comment: BTW, "13am" is nonstandard notation. Normally for the US, you'd write 1pm, but you could use military time, 1300.

Answer (score 0):

wjandrea answered what I needed, thanks
`time(1) <= datetime.now().time() <= time(13)`